# Distinguish direct access from internal access in Proxy get handler

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I have an array:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I create a proxy for that array with a `get` handler, which will return property with `n - 1` index for every number `n`. For example, `p[1]` will return `'a'`, `p[2]` – `'b'` and `p[3]` – `'c'`.

```
const p = new Proxy(arr, {
  get: (target, property, receiver) => {
    const parsed = parseInt(property, 10)
    if (!Number.isNaN(parsed)) return target[parsed - 1]
    return target[property]
  }
})
```

It seems to be working fine. `p[2]`, for instance, gives `'b'` as it should. However, there's another problem. `Array.prototype.indexOf()` is not working correctly anymore. It does work when I pass `'a'` or `'b'` – it returns respectively `1` and `2`, but for `'c'` it returns `-1`. It turns out that `indexOf()` also triggers the `get` handler. By adding `console.log(property)` to the `get` handler we get the following output for `p.indexOf('c')`:

```
'indexOf'
'length'
'0'
'1'
'2'
```

It seems that `indexOf()` internally checks the `length` property, and then iterates the array from index `0` to `length - 1`.

It would be trivial to fix that if I knew whether the property is accessed directly (like `p[2]`) or internally. Then I could always return `target[property]` for internal access (so the proxy would be no-op).

**How to distinguish direct access from internal access in Proxy `get` handler?**

The only thing that comes to my mind is throwing an error, catching it and analyzing its stack. Still, this seems to be rather a workaround than an actual solution, so I would like to avoid it, unless there's no other way.

Comment: Why are you adopting these off-by-one semantics? Nostalgia for some 1-based language?

Comment: @torazaburo I am just experimenting a bit, to find out if it's possible to create an array with indexes starting from 1, instead of 0.

Comment: I think, but am not sure, that you will have to implement a get on your object for the `indexOf` method and do the necessary manipulations.

Comment: @torazaburo Based on your suggestion, I came up with [this](https://jsbin.com/kiziguwuwa/1/edit?js,console). Do you mind if I self-answer the question with this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by torazaburo in comments, one possible solution is to return a different function for the `indexOf` property in the `get` handler and do the necessary manipulation there. Specifically, we can make the `indexOf()` method work on the original array, instead of the proxy; and add `1` to the result.

```
if (property === 'indexOf') {
  return (...args) => {
    const result = Reflect.apply(target.indexOf, target, args)
    return result === -1 ? result : result + 1
  }
}
```

Working code snippet:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const p = new Proxy(arr, {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {
    if (property === 'indexOf') {
      return (...args) => {
        const result = Reflect.apply(target.indexOf, target, args)
        return result === -1 ? result : result + 1
      }
    }
    const parsed = parseInt(property, 10)
    if (!Number.isNaN(parsed)) return target[parsed - 1]
    return target[property]
  }
})
console.log(p.indexOf('c'))
```

Other array methods can be fixed analogically.

Comment: Oh, finally `if(p.indexOf(…))` works as most people expect :-)

Comment: @Bergi I forgot about it. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that `indexOf()` internally checks the `length` property, and then iterates the array from index `0` to `length - 1`.

Yes. That's the behaviour of all builtin array methods.

> How to distinguish direct access from internal access in Proxy get handler?

You cannot.

> It would be trivial to fix that if I knew whether the property is accessed directly or internally.

No, that's the wrong approach. Something is off with your semantics if you expect `forEach` to behave differently than a normal loop. Maybe you actually want to intercept the `.length` property as well? Or wrap-around the index `0`? Without knowing the problem you're trying to solve, we can hardly suggest anything useful.

An extreme measure would be to write your own versions of all the array methods to deal with one-indexed arrays.

Comment: Rewriting all array methods has a great downside (beside having to write them): the methods would be slower than native methods.

Comment: Well, the native methods work on zero-based arrays, so you just can't have that cake and eat it. Btw, they likely will not be that much slower.

Comment: Well, I think I can. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38919913/3853934).

Comment: @Gothdo: Well, that is essentially your own version of `indexOf` (and probably quite slow as well because of the closure that makes it bound to `arr`). It's also pretty weird that `p.indexOf !== p.indexOf`.